# 80 pin SCSI Raid Controller to SATA SSD's on IBM e336

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ssd, ibm, scsi

I have an Old IBM e336 1U Sever. Currently the only Hard drive in the system is a Ultra160  SCSI drive. This drive is old and making some noises indicating that its life is going to end soon. Though my data is backed up I need something to run the OS off of. With the hard Drive installed I have booted off of a USB key no problem. When I remove the Hardrive I can no longer boot from USB or DVD. On the board there are 2 Sata ports. Labeled Left and Right, But neither of these seem to detect any devices attached to them and in the BIOS it seems to only have 2 hard drive locations which I can only assume are the 2 SCSI Drive bays.

I seem to have run out of Options as 80pin SCSI to Sata seems to be impossible. 
And once the SCSI drive is dead I do not know if I will be able to boot from USB.
 
1.  Can Anyone recommend a way to use a modern drive with a SCSI controller?

2. I have looked at PCI SSD's But have been told you cannot use these as boot devices either?
3. Anyone with experience with the IBM e336 know how to Enable the SATA ports?

> [The xSeries 306 server also has a 1U form factor, but supports uniprocessor operations and only fixed Ultra320 SCSI or SATA HDDs](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS105-472)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would dump the server. It's 10+ years old. So your options for newer disks are extremely limited. SATA was introduced on server chipsets around the time this server was released. I wouldn't put much hope in using those ports.

Your best option is to add another period-correct SCSI drive. They're readily available on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the machine is EOL twice over, it's time for it to go. If you insist on keeping it around, you might be able to find an old SATA or SAS controller on ebay, which will fit a slot on the server's mobo, and use that controller with new drives. But again, this machine isn't worth the power it is consuming and the cost of a new controller too.